# DocuSign API: Auto-place (anchor tagging) doesn't work

Tags: docusignapi, sign

I'm trying to use anchor tagging when I create a new envelope but it doesn't work.
I've tried many solution and nothing works.
Can you help me ?

Here is an example of my JSON sent to DocuSign.
I don't mention the others "parts" of the request but it contains the attached file to sign, as well.

```
{
   "emailSubject":"Signature Request",
   "emailBlurb":"Email content",
   "status":"created",
   "documents":[
      {
         "documentId":4503,
         "name":"TestSignHere.pdf",
         "order":"1",
         "documentFields":[
            {
               "name":"fileGuid",
               "value":"C8343481-65F6-462E-A9CD-D00B15535AFA"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "tabs":{
      "signHereTabs":[
         {
            "anchorString":"\\s1\\",
            "anchorXOffset":"1",
            "anchorYOffset":"0",
            "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent":"false",
            "anchorUnits":"inches"
         }
      ]
   },
   "recipients":{
      "signers":[
         {
            "name":"Test test",
            "email":"test@test.com",
            "recipientId":"1D5E68FF-BD1E-EB11-BEDA-F8AC6521C37E"
         }
      ]
   },
   "eventNotification":{
      "url":"https:\/\/test.com",
      "loggingEnabled":"true",
      "requireAcknowledgment":"false",
      "useSoapInterface":"false",
      "soapNameSpace":"http:\/\/DocuSignConnectListener",
      "includeCertificateWithSoap":"false",
      "signMessageWithX509Cert":"false",
      "includeDocuments":"false",
      "includeEnvelopeVoidReason":"false",
      "includeTimeZone":"false",
      "includeSenderAccountAsCustomField":"false",
      "includeDocumentFields":"false",
      "includeCertificateOfCompletion":"false",
      "envelopeEvents":[
         {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode":"Sent"
         },
         {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode":"Delivered"
         },
         {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode":"Completed"
         },
         {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode":"Declined"
         },
         {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode":"Voided"
         }
      ],
      "recipientEvents":[
         {
            "recipientEventStatusCode":"AuthenticationFailed"
         },
         {
            "recipientEventStatusCode":"AutoResponded"
         },
         {
            "recipientEventStatusCode":"Completed"
         },
         {
            "recipientEventStatusCode":"Declined"
         },
         {
            "recipientEventStatusCode":"Delivered"
         },
         {
            "recipientEventStatusCode":"Sent"
         }
      ]
   },
   "notification":{
      "useAccountDefaults":"true"
   }
}
```

And here is my document.
It's just a simple example with my anchor text inside.

[image]

I've also tried with the following tab configuration and it didn't work.

```
   "tabs":{
      "signHereTabs":[
         {
            "documentId":4494,
            "recipientId":"D4E013B9-B71E-EB11-BEDA-F8AC6521C37E",
            "tabLabel":"test test",
            "pageNumber":"2",
            "xPosition":"10",
            "yPosition":"10"
         }
      ]
   },
```

Or

```
   "tabs":{
      "signHereTabs":[
         {
            "anchorString":"##SIGN_HERE##"
         }
      ]
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't put the node "tabs" at the right place.
Here is a good solution.
Tabs should be under "signers".

```
{
   "emailSubject":"Signature Request",
   "emailBlurb":"Email content",
   "status":"created",
   "documents":[
      {
         "documentId":4503,
         "name":"TestSignHere.pdf",
         "order":"1",
         "documentFields":[
            {
               "name":"fileGuid",
               "value":"C8343481-65F6-462E-A9CD-D00B15535AFA"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "recipients":{
      "signers":[
         {
            "name":"Test test",
            "email":"test@test.com",
            "recipientId":"1D5E68FF-BD1E-EB11-BEDA-F8AC6521C37E",
            "tabs":{
               "signHereTabs":[
                  {
                     "anchorString":"\\s1\\"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "eventNotification":{
      "url":"https:\/\/test.com",
      "loggingEnabled":"true",
      "requireAcknowledgment":"false",
      "useSoapInterface":"false",
      "soapNameSpace":"http:\/\/DocuSignConnectListener",
      "includeCertificateWithSoap":"false",
      "signMessageWithX509Cert":"false",
      "includeDocuments":"false",
      "includeEnvelopeVoidReason":"false",
      "includeTimeZone":"false",
      "includeSenderAccountAsCustomField":"false",
      "includeDocumentFields":"false",
      "includeCertificateOfCompletion":"false",
      "envelopeEvents":[
         {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode":"Sent"
         },
         {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode":"Delivered"
         },
         {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode":"Completed"
         },
         {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode":"Declined"
         },
         {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode":"Voided"
         }
      ],
      "recipientEvents":[
         {
            "recipientEventStatusCode":"AuthenticationFailed"
         },
         {
            "recipientEventStatusCode":"AutoResponded"
         },
         {
            "recipientEventStatusCode":"Completed"
         },
         {
            "recipientEventStatusCode":"Declined"
         },
         {
            "recipientEventStatusCode":"Delivered"
         },
         {
            "recipientEventStatusCode":"Sent"
         }
      ]
   },
   "notification":{
      "useAccountDefaults":"true"
   }
}
```